# Better way to import modules in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I need a cleaner way to import the modules into the test_file.py, I am using pytest for my test. My present pytest setup is like the below which works, but I need a more organised way to import the modules into the test functions without initializing the database client. The global variable is breaking my test when I import using the cleaner way.

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def no_request_cassandra_client(mocker):
    """Remove cassandra.cluster.Cluster for all tests."""
    mock_cass_cluster = mocker.patch("cassandra.cluster.Cluster")
```

**test_file.py**

```
import pytest

def test_car_class(no_request_cassandra_client): 
    from A.BMW import car
    car_func = car()
    assert car_func
```

**This is what I want to have, but the car method has a global variable like the BMW.py, the test is breaking because of the Cluster(["Cluster_ip_address"]) with the cleaner solution.**

**Cleaner test_file.py**

```
import pytest
from A.BMW import car

def test_car_class(): 
    car_func = car()
    assert car_func
```

**BMW.py**

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster(["Cluster_ip_address"])
def car():
    x = 2 + 3
    print(x)
    return x
```

Comment: When you do `from A.BMW import car` it should also import `A.BMW` so the global variable `cluster` should be there and defined. I don't see the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the import of car is also calling `cluster = Cluster(["Cluster_ip_address"])` which is a global variable in BMW.py. @xjcl

Comment: Oh that is the problem. I guess there is nothing you can do except not make it a global variable.

Comment: Yeah, this is a general problem with Global variables. I was trying to see if there is a workaround for this now..